# In C# code analysis, how to know if a TypeSyntax is an Enum?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

[image]

In my code, I have already captured this TypeSyntax, which is an IdentifierNameSyntax. It is an Enum, as shown in the image, under "Properties", the Classification is "Enum Name". But I don't know how to get this in my program. Seem like it have something to do with the semantic model.

It was done under given `GeneratorExecutionContext context`, so semantic model can be get `context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(typeSyntax.SyntaxTree)`, you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track!
Currently you have the syntactic information in hand, and you may indeed query semantic information through the [SemanticModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.semanticmodel).

First, ask for the [TypeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.typeinfo) of that expression:

```
TypeInfo typeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(typeSyntax, context.CancellationToken);
ITypeSymbol? type = typeInfo.Type;

if (type is INamedTypeSymbol { TypeKind: TypeKind.Enum } symbol)
{
    Debug.Assert(type is not IErrorTypeSymbol);
    Debug.Assert(type.SpecialType != SpecialType.System_Enum);
}
```

With this you can get hold of more semantic information about that [enum type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum), such as its members and their names, or the *underlying type* of the *enum type* which is [int](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32) per default:

```
IEnumerable<string> memberNames = type
    .GetMembers()
    .Where(static member => member.Kind is SymbolKind.Field)
    .Select(static symbol => symbol.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.FullyQualifiedFormat));

INamedTypeSymbol? underlyingType = symbol.EnumUnderlyingType;
Debug.Assert(underlyingType is not null);
```